# Store html elements in object and wait ng-include include template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to use this code:

```
   var Table = function($elem) {
     this.PROPERTIE.element = $elem;

     this.init();
   };

   Table.prototype.PROPERTIE = {
     secondElement: $('.second') // this exists in the HTML
   };

   Table.prototype.init = function() {
     console.log(this.PROPERTIE.element) -> output the element;
     console.log(this.PROPERTIE.secondElement) -> undefined
   };


    var tableDirective = function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'M',
            link: function($scope, $elem) {
                return new Table($elem);
            }
        };
    };

angular.module('app').directive('tableDirective', tableDirective);
```

If i try to get an html element inside any method of my constructor class, i can, but if i try to store the same element in a object, he will be undefined.

It is very obvious why for me. Is because the $('.second'); doesn't exist when the PROPERTIE object try to rich them, because the element is inside an template, and i'm pulling this template with ng-include.

There is anything that i can solve this problem? Wait the ng-include before the script runs or something related? I alredy try to use the $timeout and setTimeout.

Thanks in advance, guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
Table.prototype.PROPERTIE = {
  secondElement: function(){ return $('.second')}
};

Table.prototype.init = function() {
  console.log(this.PROPERTIE.element)
  console.log(this.PROPERTIE.secondElement())
};
```

You were calling the jq function `$('.second')` during the definition of the `Table.prototype.PROPERTIE` which was happening when the script got loaded.  Changing it to a method works because you're not assigning anything when the script loads.